# Rails how to make form_for input text area wider?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to make the input field wider but I can only make it longer. I've tried other suggestions on stackoverflow like "cols" => 50 but that does't do anything.

I have this currently.

```
    <%= f.text_area  :text, "width" => 80, "rows" => 20 %>
```

And width doesn't work either, any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

You can use cols and rows, but i usually use css to style the form. You can set a class to this text area:

```
<%= f.text_area :text, class: "your_class" %>
```

And then in your stylesheets:

```
.your_class{
  width:100%;
}
```

Here is the doc for more details: [doc](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-text_area)

Answer (score 2):

This code should work

```
<%= f.text_area :text, :cols => 80, :rows => 20 %>
```